# firebase: admin.auth().updateUser() causes auth/user-token-expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

1. I successfully auth with phone-number. (I can check `firebase.auth.currentUser` that I'm logged in.)
2. Then I'm calling my firebase admin route which have `admin.auth().updateUser(uid, somevalues)` to set user displayName and email.
3. After this step finished and my user data changed displayName and email.(It is checked in firebase console)
   In my auth I run `firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()` to get updated user data and suddenly there is error **auth/user-token-expired**
   I have checked only after I use admin.auth().updateUser(....) my token is lost. If I do not run this command then I can do firebase.auth().currentUser.reload() without problem.

UPDATE: Only if I set email when calling admin.auth().updateUser(....) my token inside app becomes invalid. If I change only displayName token remains valid.

Comment: Do you also have email auth enabled in your Firebase account? If so, invalidation of the token would make sense as a security precaution.

Comment: Oh. So I can t have phone auth and email auth at the same time?

Comment: No, actually you can have both (and Firebase actually suggests that). But, if your account is set to allow users to auth with email, I would think the token is reliant on that credential whether you knew it or not. So, changing the credential (email address) would invalidate the token. Otherwise, it makes it easier to steal another user's token and session.

Comment: @misterfancypants what should I do then to not have this error and still able to change email?

Comment: Unfortunately I think Jeremy Lee is correct below: according to Firebase's documentation, this is not an error. You might want to warn your users that they will have to re-auth before they change their email.

Comment: I understand but I never saw an app or site where after changing email I had to reauthorize. Its just a bad UX. What I did is extracted  email update from cloud functions and executed it from client auth. So I updated email and did not reauthorized.

Comment: Strange, I've actually seen that behavior when I change my email more often than not (it's a pain, but is more secure). I think your workaround makes sense!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact question is here, but `reload()` will use a refresh token, however, refresh tokens expire when **"A major account change is detected for the user. This includes events like password or email address updates."**

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions

So when your refresh token expires (due to the 'major account change'), you need to re-authorize..

Comment: So what is correct way to change email and do not have the this error?

Comment: Also if I turn off email authorization this error STILL persist

Comment: @rendom it's not an error. The email is considered a major account change, so, by design, you need to re-authorize the account

Answer (score 0):

In  my case I was accidentally making an update to the current user in Firestore Auth twice. You might want to check for that.